# How to configure chef system on redhat/centos?

Tags: virtual-machine, chef-infra

I want to install chef server,client and workstation on centos.
I am referring to this article

- http://sachinsharm.wordpress.com/2013/10/11/installsetup-and-configure-chef-serverworkstationnode-on-centosrhel-6-4/

So i want to know what will be structure of chef server, client and workstation on OS vm machines.

Suppose i have 3 machines so shall i install these 3 separatly or 2 machines will be enough.

Plz help me with structure so i will get clear idea how chef actually works on VM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The chef documentation provides an excellent diagram that explains the relationship between:

- chef server
- chef workstation
- chef node

[image]

In summary:

- The [chef server](http://docs.opscode.com/chef_overview_server.html) provides a central repository for configuration data.
- The chef nodes are the servers under management, running [chef-client](http://docs.opscode.com/essentials_chef_client.html).
- A chef workstation is a machine configured to use the [knife](http://docs.opscode.com/knife.html)
  command.